# Silverlight support from Microsoft

Tags: silverlight

I heard Silverlight will not be supported any more by Microsoft. It is true? If so, could anyone share with me Microsoft announcement? And if there are already application developed by Silverlight, what is the new technology to migration to?

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft will no longer support, or at least does not encourage, use of Silverlight on the desktop but still advocates its usage on mobile. I'll try and find the link.

[First I heard of it.](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-our-strategy-with-silverlight-has-shifted/7834)
[A developer's complaint.](http://www.itwriting.com/blog/6924-microsoft-silverlight-shattered-into-a-million-broken-urls.html)

Comment: Thanks Rob. If I have already used Silverlight, what kinds of new technologies should I migrate to?

Comment: @LinMa That depends on what you are trying to do. Choose the right tool for each job.

Comment: If I want to setup a video web site like Youtube, people could upload and play video in browser. Any good suggestions?

Comment: Supporting both Flash and HTML5 is probably the safest way.

Comment: @LinMa - The little bit we've done, we just use the video elements and canvas but you have to watch for the usual IE problems you'll have as we always do. I've never used Silverlight so I'm not the best source for alternatives to that.

Comment: Thanks Niphra and Rob. I want to setup a small scale video management web site, which allow people to upload and render video from browser. Any open source project to recommend? If based on PHP + MySQL + HTML5 (which support both PC, tablet and mobile phone), it will be great.